# Java Applet get hanged when i try to run from browser

Tags: java, applet

[image]

Some time My browser get hanged when i run applet i am not able to click on accept check box.

Kindly help me..

Comment: @andrew-thompson do you have any idea please

Comment: *"any idea"* 1)  Sign the applet with a real code signing certificate. 2) Launch the applet free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).